# Is there an Java function to transform an array of ordered pair to an array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a Java project where I have to convert a 2D array of ordered pairs to an array of integers.

In order to clarify what I need please consider the following array as example:

```
int [][] arrayUno = {{0,1},{1,0},{2,1},{2,2},{1,1},{1,2},{0,2},{2,0},{0,0}}
```

Let's say that we have another array of the same length:

```
int [][] arrayDos = {{0,0},{0,1},{0,2},{1,0},{1,1},{1,2},{2,0},{2,1},{2,2}}
```

Every ordered pair is unique in every array (represent a specific combination of jobs/machine, i.e. {0,2} is the operation of job 0 in machine 2).

I want to have the position of every element (ordered pair) of arrayUno in arrayDos. The result must be:

```
{2,4,8,9,5,6,3,7,1}
```

For example, the first element of arrayUno ({0,1}) is in the 2° position of arrayDos; element {1,0} of arrayUno is in the 4° position of arrayDos; element {2,1} of arrayUno is in the 8° position of arrayDos and so on.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class OrderedPair {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arrayOne = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}};

        int[][] arrayTwo = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

        OrderedPair pair = new OrderedPair();

        int[] transformed = pair.transform(arrayOne, arrayTwo);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(transformed));
    }

    private int[] transform(int[][] dictionary, int[][] lookup) {
        int[] result = new int[dictionary.length];

        for (int index = 0; index < lookup.length; index++) {
            int[] pair = lookup[index];

            int indexOf = -1;

            for (int dictionaryIndex = 0; dictionaryIndex < dictionary.length; dictionaryIndex++) {
                int[] dictionaryPair = dictionary[dictionaryIndex];

                if (dictionaryPair[0] == pair[0] && dictionaryPair[1] == pair[1]) {
                    indexOf = dictionaryIndex;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (indexOf != -1) {
                result[index] = indexOf;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I expect the output: `{2,4,8,9,5,6,3,7,1}`

But the output is: `{8,0,6,1,4,5,7,2,3}`

Comment: if you want the position, your result should be {1,3,7,8,4,5,2,6,0}, because we count from 0.

Comment: ok @vs97 this would be also helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the inner loop on the outside, and the outer loop on the inside!

Inside of saying:

```
For each pair x in array one
    For each pair y in array two
        If x and y are equal
            ...
```

You did:

```
For each pair x in array two
    For each pair y in array one
        If x and y are equal
            ...
```

So to make your code work, you just have to pass the arguments in the reverse order:

```
int[] transformed = pair.transform(arrayTwo, arrayOne);
```

OR, an I recommend this, switch the loops around:

```
private int[] transform(int[][] dictionary, int[][] lookup) {
    int[] result = new int[dictionary.length];

    for (int dictionaryIndex = 0; dictionaryIndex < dictionary.length; dictionaryIndex++) {
        int[] dictionaryPair = dictionary[dictionaryIndex];

        int indexOf = -1;

        for (int index = 0; index < lookup.length; index++) {
            int[] pair = lookup[index];
            if (dictionaryPair[0] == pair[0] && dictionaryPair[1] == pair[1]) {
                indexOf = index;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (indexOf != -1) {
            result[dictionaryIndex] = indexOf;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can create objects and use more memory it is easy as next:

```
public class Main {

  static class Pair {
    private int[] a;

    Pair(int[] a) {
      this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
      Pair pair = (Pair) o;
      return Arrays.equals(a, pair.a);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Arrays.hashCode(a);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arrayOne = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}};
    int[][] arrayTwo = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

    List<Pair> lookup = Stream.of(arrayTwo).map(Pair::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Pair> dictionary = Stream.of(arrayOne).map(Pair::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Integer> result = dictionary.stream().map(lookup::indexOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
  }

}
```

create a class that represents each pair and implement equals and hashCode methods so we can use indexOf to find an index of needed pair in the lookup collection.

Without additional objects:

```
private int[] transform(int[][] dictionary, int[][] lookup) {
    int[] result = new int[dictionary.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < lookup.length; j++) {
        if (lookup[j][0] == dictionary[i][0] && lookup[j][1] == dictionary[i][1]) {
          result[i] = j;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```